# Cannot find the X.509 certificate when browsing wcf services in browser

Tags: wcf, iis-7, publish

I Published a service on IIS 7. I used a self signed certificate named testCertificate. when I browse the service in the browser I get this error:
Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria: StoreName 'Root', StoreLocation 'LocalMachine', FindType 'FindBySubjectName', FindValue 'testCertificate'.
I used this code in my Web.Config file:

```
    <serviceCredentials>                        
        <serviceCertificate findValue="testCertificate" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyService.Authentication,MyService" />
    </serviceCredentials>
```

And another point is when I referesh the browser page I get this error:
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
could any one help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the X509 certificate in the store location

> Store --> Root --> LocalMachine

Type **`mmc`** in the **Run** to add certificate

Comment: I published this service on a server but I want it be accessible from some other computers in our local network. so in mmc sould I select user account or computer account? Also I couldn't find Root and LocalMachine in mmc.